# Update with a case when (one row joined with multiple rows) - Execution plan question

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-update, case

The following test case

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#a') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #a

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#b') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #b

CREATE TABLE #a (
    [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [PickedPriority] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #a([Value])
VALUES('Test')

CREATE TABLE #b (
    [RowId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ColumnMiddlePriority] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [ColumnTopPriority] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [ColumnLowPriority] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    PRIMARY KEY([RowId])
)
INSERT INTO #b([ColumnLowPriority])
VALUES(N'Test')
INSERT INTO #b([ColumnTopPriority])
VALUES(N'Test')
INSERT INTO #b([ColumnMiddlePriority])
VALUES(N'Test')

UPDATE A
SET
    A.[PickedPriority] = CASE 
        WHEN B.[ColumnTopPriority] = A.[Value] THEN N'TOP' 
        WHEN B.[ColumnMiddlePriority] = A.[Value] THEN N'MIDDLE' 
        WHEN B.[ColumnLowPriority] = A.[Value] THEN N'LOW' 
        END
FROM #a A
    INNER JOIN #b B ON (
        A.[Value] = B.[ColumnLowPriority]
        OR A.[Value] = B.[ColumnTopPriority]
        OR A.[Value] = B.[ColumnMiddlePriority]
    )
```

produces result: PickedPriority is always TOP even if I try to change the order of insertion in table #b.

When I check the execution plan, I can understand why: a GROUP BY is operated after matching A row and B rows, then the left to right testing of the case when do the trick, but is the result deterministic here ?

Does a different execution plan could end up with a different result ?

[image]

Comment: Execution plans are never guaranteed, unless you include hints that restrict the plan to very specific algorithms.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your answer, you're right, Ive updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer in this article:
https://sqlperformance.com/2019/07/sql-performance/the-any-aggregate-is-broken 
and in the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#best-practices

So no, in my case (multiple lines matching one line in an update statement), not deterministic at all.